# Add a hatch pattern over a linear-gradient in a div

Tags: html, css, design-patterns, linear-gradients

I have a div with a linear-gradiant as background. This gradient is created with a color parameter. But I also want to show a diagonal hatch pattern over the gradient.

```
"background: linear-gradient(" + color2 + "," + color + ")"
```

I've created the hatch pattern with another linear-gradient:

```
background: linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black   75%, black), linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black); 
background-size: 4px 4px;
background-position: 0 0, 2px 2px;
```

I'm not able to show the two linear-gradient at the same time.

Comment: You're not able to show the two linear-gradients when you you do it programatically, or not at all? What browser are you using? This works for me in Chrome 33.0.1750.154

Comment: Only the first one is shown, I use 33.0.1750.154

Comment: Have you tried using `background-image` instead of `background`?

Comment: Can you give me the css you used?

Comment: The only thing that is different is `background-image` instead of `background`. Which isn't an issue with CSS, but could be if added or modified with code. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X77Tf/). I'm now noticing that Chrome is having rendering issues on the fiddle page. It may work on page load, but once you move the window around, the overlapping gradient disappears.

Comment: I also want to have a 2 colors gradient below the pattern, I achieve it by having div like in the Pete's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is important. Your last background-image will be rendered first, so this one has to be the non transparent one.

And also, you need to keep all the related properties, size and origin:

```
.div1 {
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black  75%, black), 
        linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black),
        linear-gradient(#f00000,#ffffff);
    background-size: 4px 4px, 4px 4px, 100% 100%;    
    background-position: 0px 0px, 2px 2px, 0px 0px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PnYq9/1/)

Answer (score 2):

you could have nested divs and then apply the styles separately:

Html

```
<div class="div1"><div class="div2"></div></div>
```

Css

```
.div1 {background: linear-gradient(#f00000,#ffffff)}
.div2 
{
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black  75%, black), linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black); 
    background-size: 4px 4px;
    background-position: 0 0, 2px 2px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PnYq9/)